# Moodle-Mahara Integration Automaticall Creating groups & assigning users to groups in Mahara

Tags: php, web-services, moodle, mahara

I have a functional integrated system of Moodle (2.2) and Mahara (1.4) connected with mnet.

I was wondering if below are possible:

- If a course is created in Moodle, can a group be created in Mahara automatically with the same course name. (As mentioned in the road map of Mahara).

https://wiki.mahara.org/index.php/Roadmap

- If a user enrolls in a course in Moodle can the user be assigned to a group automatically.
- If a user completes a course in Moodle, can a protfolio on Mahara be populated automatically.

Do I need to use webservices to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible and might be a bit of a headache to implement with webservices. Given that you control both systems, a far simpler solution would be to write a custom script that would run via cron and read/write directly to the databases. We are not yet able to do the above, but are planning to write some code that will do so, possibly open sourcing it later.